# Is there  a way to fix the call answer delay?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, calls, htc-incredible-s

This is a known Android issue which has been widely reported ([example](http://androidforums.com/nexus-support-troubleshooting/97121-delay-answering-incoming-calls.html)).

I saw a suggestion to use [Call Delay Patch](https://market.android.com/search?q=pname%3acz.byteworks.cdp) from the Android Market, but some report that this helps while others report that it doesn't work.

I have the same issue on my HTC Incredible S (Android 2.3.3) and want to know if this issue has been addressed already or if there is a patch for it or a way to avoid it. Searching the web brings only complaints.

Comment: I just got in the habbit of saying "hello" twice... but I have not seen a patch for it. my only real suggestion is to "star" the issue so google will fix it. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16230

Comment: Yes I did star that already, but the issue is up for a rather long time so I hoped that a workaround was already found maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, this issue has been resolved with Gingerbread 2.3.5. I no longer have the issue with my device running Gingerbread 2.3.5 (actually i think CM7 is based on 2.3.7 now). From what I am seeing in the [reported issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16230) is other people are saying the same thing about it being fixed. I am not sure if your device has an update available or not though.